# Amazon OpsWorks NodeJS environment variables

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I configured a stack for a NodeJS application server using Amazon OpsWorks.

I need to access some environment variables which define Google API credentials. How can I achieve this ? I already spent more two days on this.

I ended up by the following chef recipe :

```
magic_shell_environment "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID" do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    value "********"
    mode  '0600'
end
```

I use the root account because it seems the NodeJS is run under that account. If I remove the `owner` and `group` attributes, I can read those environment variables fine (as the default `ubuntu` user). However, when I ssh to my instance and type `echo $GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID` as root, I get an empty string.

Also, where is logged the output of `console.xxxx(...)` ?

Comment: Is this a first-run? Environment variables aren't set until the second run

Comment: Do you mean that I have to restart the instance once after the configure step?

Comment: No - I mean during the first Chef run, the env variables aren't loaded yet

Answer (score 1):

OpsWorks now lets you specify up to 20 custom environment variables in the app settings page. In the case of a node.js app these will be available in the process.env object. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [OpsWorksEnvy](https://github.com/vlamic/OpsWorksEnvy) cookbook.  It hooks nicely into the default nodejs cookbooks and lets you set the environment variables in your stack attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly easy to do. Just add the following line to the top of your recipe.

```
ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID']="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
```